# How to uncheck radio button in different listview in same layout.?

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radio-group

I have cleared many problems about radio buttons but this was in my mind since many days. I have 5 radio buttons in different list view please tell me how to uncheck any radio button while accessing other and get the value of selected radio button. 
following are the codes.

custom_dialogue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded,NestedWeights,UselessParent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="8" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#E3EBED"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Screen timeout"
                android:textColor="#449BA4"
                android:textSize="21sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rg_all"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="15 seconds"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_15sec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="30 seconds"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_30sec"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="1 minute"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_1min"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="2 minutes"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_2min"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="5 minutes"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_5min"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F5F5F5"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:text="10 minutes"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_10min"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_cancel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#C9DCE0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomDialogue.java

```
package com.example.coustomdialogue;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomDialogue extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogue);

        final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg_all);


    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_10min);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_15sec);
    final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_1min);
    final RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_2min);
    final RadioButton rb5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_30sec);
    final RadioButton rb6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rb_5min);


    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override

        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

        if(checkedId == R.id.rb_10min){
            rg.clearCheck();
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
            rb5.setChecked(false);
            rb6.setChecked(false);
        }else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_15sec){
            rg.clearCheck();
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb3.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
            rb5.setChecked(false);
            rb6.setChecked(false);
        }else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_1min){
            rg.clearCheck();
            rb2.setChecked(false);
            rb4.setChecked(false);
            rb1.setChecked(false);
            rb5.setChecked(false);
            rb6.setChecked(false);
            }else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_2min){
                rg.clearCheck();
                rb2.setChecked(false);
                rb3.setChecked(false);
                rb5.setChecked(false);
                rb1.setChecked(false);
                rb6.setChecked(false);
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.rb_30sec){
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb6.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    }else{
                        rg.clearCheck();
                        rb2.setChecked(false);
                        rb2.setChecked(false);
                        rb3.setChecked(false);
                        rb4.setChecked(false);
                        rb5.setChecked(false);
                        rb1.setChecked(false);
                    }

        }

        });

}
}
```

Comment: May this gives you some idea http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/single-selection-mode-for-listview-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the real Answer for the following I solved my problem as I used a Click event on every radio button. Whenever I click on the radio Button at that time i change the checked to uncheck if any. No need to use RadioGroup. 
Hope this helped you all.